# Is it possible to define a precedence before using aggregate operators in sql?

Tags: sql

It is possible to define a precedence to use min()/max() aggregations?

| status | name |
| --- | --- |
| true | first |
| false | second |
| true | third |
| false | fourth |

For instance, fourth > third > second > first

```
select status, max(name) from table group by 1;
```

expected result:

| status | name |
| --- | --- |
| true | third |
| false | fourth |

Comment: Sure, you can use CASE, set 1 for first, 2 for second etc. and build max over the result.

Comment: Please tag the question with the SQL server tag, like, MySQL, PostGres etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using row_number window function if supported by the DBMS used.

```
   select status,
           name
    from (   select status,
                    name,
                    row_number() over(partition by status 
                                                 order by case when name='first' then 1
                                                               when name='second' then 2
                                                               when name='third' then 3
                                                               when name='fourth' then 4 end desc ) as max_name
              from tablename 
         ) x
    where  max_name=1 ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wx6R7g3I

The key part is the partition and order by clause. The case expression assign the respective 1,2,3,4 numbers for the first ,second ,third ,fourth keyword ordering in descending .